# Change orientation on gradient

Tags: echarts

So I'm trying to create a gradient fill for a line chart. The thing about this gradient is that I need it to have a color according to a given value.

So, what I was thinking is that if I could change the orientation of the gradient (from side to side instead of down-up) I could give it a color scheme based on the values. However, I haven't been able to "transpose" the gradient.

My expected result is something like this:

Another value (a 3rd one), which is not the line value (Y-axis), or the date (X-axis) gives the color for the gradient at any X-axis point

[image]

Any ideas?
Thanks!